# Start multiple threads at the same time without slowing down

Tags: c#, multithreading, loops, foreach

I know that this question is everywhere but I couldn't find what suits me.

I am trying to start 10 threads running at the same time without slowing down each thread.

My problem is that when I start the threads manually, they are very fast. But if I start them using a loop, they are very slow.

Here is where it is fast:

```
            Thread tid1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid1.Start();
            Thread tid2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid2.Start();
            Thread tid3 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid3.Start();
            Thread tid4 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid4.Start();
            Thread tid5 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid5.Start();
            Thread tid6 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid6.Start();
            Thread tid7 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid7.Start();
            Thread tid8 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid8.Start();
            Thread tid9 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid9.Start();
            Thread tid10 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
            tid10.Start();
```

Slow methods which I've tried:

1:

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, 10))
{
    Thread tid = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
    tid.Start();
}
```

2:

```
Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), i => 
{
        Thread tid = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Thread));
        tid.Start();
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You are calling a constructor ThreadStart.  What code is in the constructor?  The constuctor has to complete executing before the next thread starts.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in general? why do you need to start them simultaneously

Comment: @TheGeneral - Because I have a lot of work to do, that's why I want it to be faster.

Comment: "I have a lot of work to do" isn't exactly an explanation of why this is an issue. Surely using the `Parallel` functionality would achieve the desired results?

Comment: Have you considered using async/await Task instead (TPL) or ThreadPool Threads? Using Plain Threads is somewhat outdated, though possible. Also, "more Threads" does not necessarily equal "faster".

Comment: Can you clarify the "fast" and "slow" meaning here ? Do you have any benchmarks, what are actual measurable results and what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @mjwills - This is .NET framework v4.6 release

Comment: Yes, I am using Release.

Comment: Please show us the code you used for benchmarking (so we can repro the issue at our end).

Comment: Do you really have a _method_ called Thread() ?  You can't and you shouldn't.

Comment: When you ask a question like this (about fine details) provide actual working and copy/pasted code, not pseudo junk. Also list actual vs expected outcomes, all relevant versions numbers etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering, this method seems quite quick:

```
List<Thread> threadlist = new List<Thread>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++)
    threadlist.Add(new Thread(new ThreadStart(wastetime)));

foreach (Thread t in threadlist)
    t.Start();
```

Make a list of the threads, then start them once the list is assembled. Bonus points if the thread creation sub is on it's own mini thread to.

Though beware of magic, each thread has overhead and extra processing involved, so if the tasks being performed on each thread are short-lived, the whole threading idea will be losing performance rather than gaining it.

Comment: This is VB.NET?

Comment: Yeah, same thing :)

Comment: Yeah, it just thread.sleeps for a few seconds, to simulate a long process.